# TFS (2015) REST Services

Tags: rest, tfs, coldfusion-9

I have been asked by a developer (Cold Fusion) to expose the REST API so they can programatically create Work Items from a in house developed application.

This is my first foray into REST within TFS and I am not to sure where to start. I checked the Microsoft documentation but it is of course biased towards .NET or client libraries, but as far as I can make out I wont be able to do anything with these as it is cold fusion environment making the "call" ?

Can I get some advice as to how I go about achieving this?

Comment: A REST call is a REST call. What **specific** difficulties are you having implementing it in your application?

Comment: Im not sure where to add it or how to create it. Everywhere I am looking specifies "/_apis" in verb,  I don't have that available, which suggest something hasn't been enabled or installed?

Comment: I't not really an application I'm trying to connect to - I have just been asked to provide an endpoint or connection string to allow an in house developed application to create work items in TFS

Comment: A REST call would look something like this http://{tfs server}:{port}/{Collection}/{Team Project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{wit id}

Comment: What do you mean by *"I don't have that available"*?  Are you getting an error message when you try to call the REST method? You need to be as specific as possible when requesting help.

Comment: ok....so Im trying to work out how I go about creating this to allow it to be consumed by an "external" application to create work items automatically. Os I looked through all the usual microsoft sources and I m get that I need to get a response from   - http://{my tfs server}:{port}/{collection}/{Project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{wit_id}  - When I enter this in to my browser I just get a "Error Page not found" message, so I assume I need to install a plugin or something to somehow enable the API element of TFS ? OR do I need to create the service using C# or something and then save it somewhere?

Comment: No, it is built in to TFS 2015 +, no plugin required. Any mechanism that you can read a url will work. I.e Chrome, Firefox, Curl, HttpClient lib in C#, cfhttp in Cold Fusion etc. I would check that the URL is correct with the correct values substituted.

Answer (score 0):

Representational State Transfer (REST) APIs are service endpoints that support sets of HTTP operations (methods), which provide create, retrieve, update, or delete access to the service's resources.

The Api to create a work item is as below:

```
POST https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${type}?api-version=4.1

[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Sample task"
  }
]
```

If you just want to test the rest api, you could download [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), and test api using it. If you want to use the rest api in the code, you could refer to the example below.

Here is an example getting a list of projects for your account:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

...

//encode your personal access token                   
string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", personalAccessToken)));

ListofProjectsResponse.Projects viewModel = null;

//use the httpclient
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://{accountname}.visualstudio.com");  //url of our account
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", credentials); 

    //connect to the REST endpoint            
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("_apis/projects?stateFilter=All&api-version=1.0").Result;

    //check to see if we have a succesfull respond
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        //set the viewmodel from the content in the response
        viewModel = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ListofProjectsResponse.Projects>().Result;

        //var value = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }   
}
```

Useful links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/?view=vsts-rest-4.1
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/work%20items/create?view=vsts-rest-4.1